# QContiguousCache is leaking memory everytime i call

Tags: qt

Im using QContiguousCache for holding item data. what i observed is, when ever i start calling QContiguousCache setCapacity it is leaking memory. for testing purpose i  start calling the QContiguousCache class in a timerEvent and the memory is shooting every-time i call.

```
void MyListModel::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if (event->timerId() == timer.timerId()) {
        qDebug()<<"Continusous cache";
        QContiguousCache<int> cache; // = new QContiguousCache<datatmp>();
        cache.setCapacity(10000);

        qDebug()<<"Cache count:"<<cache.count();
        while(cache.count())
        {
            cache.removeLast();
        }
        cache.detach();



}
}
```

i tried in heap with properly deleting it but still the same result.

Comment: Hm, `QContiguousCache` has `detach()` function? Which Qt version is it?

Comment: Qt 5.9.0 version .